# Google Action - Permission PHONE_NUMBER request does not work

Tags: user-permissions, actions-on-google

In the Actions on Google documentation I have read that you can ask for the user's phone number ([link](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Permission)) by using the 'helper' syntax with a permission request ([link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers)). But this does not work for me and the simulator stops and tells me that my Google action does not work properly. My response looks like this, according to the documentation:

```
{
 "conversationToken": "TOKEN",
 "expectUserResponse": true,
 "expectedInputs": [
   {
    "inputPrompt": {
      "initialPrompts": [
        {
          "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
        }
      ],
      "noInputPrompts": []
    },
    "possibleIntents": [
      {
        "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
        "inputValueData": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
          "optContext": "To deliver your order",
          "permissions": [
            "PHONE_NUMBER"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Do I do anything wrong here?

Comment: Do you have an intent with the event "actions.intent.PERMISSION" to handle the response?

Comment: Yes I do have it. For example in a previous step I ask for the user's device location that works fine. The assistant asks the user for this permission, but with the PHONE_NUMBER permission the assistant doesn't even ask the user to give permission for the phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake in the documentations that we are working to fix.
I hope that in the future we will have this permission.

Answer (score 0):

In your second link there's the same table as in the first link but without the Phone number and update fields. I know the update functionality is still in developer preview and can't be used yet. This is my first time seeing the option to request a phone number through permissions so I would assume that it is still a work in progress and can't be used.